# Script to remove JPG's with particular vendor tag

Tags: scripts, 14.10, jpeg

Somebody put their memory card into my smartphone, and suddenly (with auto-upload enabled) I have a folder full of photo's that are not mine on my Ubuntu machine. How can I delete JPG files that have a vendor tag of "Motorola"? I am looking for a script, probably using the EXIF program (that I have installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably tons of different ways there but here's a pythonic one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, glob
for filename in glob.glob('*.*'):
    if os.popen('exif %s | grep Manufacturer | grep Motorola' % filename).read():
        os.remove(filename)
```

Yeah, the filepattern is `*.*` and it simply checks for words Manufacturer and Motorola in the same line from the `exif` results per filename and removes that file if found (i.e. there's a readable output from the command pipe).

Comment: You probably want to add quotation marks around %s too if there happens to be file names with spaces.